# Parsing crypto ECDH public key into JWK format to use it with WebCrypto

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, webcrypto-api, jwk

I generated an ECDH key pair, and get the public key from it. Using nodejs and the crypto library.

```
const ecdh = crypto.createECDH('secp384r1');
ecdh.generateKeys();
const publicKey = ecdh.getPublicKey('hex');
```

I'm implementing a client side library to encrypt data using this public key, the ECDH algorithm and the [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) interface from WebCrypto.

To Accomplish this I have to import the public key (Generated with nodejs crypto), WebCrypto [importKey method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey) has some format options to do it, but I can get it to work with non of them. I noticed that `jwk` is more used than the others.

An example of a `jwk` is

```
{  
  kty: "EC",
  crv: "P-256",
  x: "kgR_PqO07L8sZOBbw6rvv7O_f7clqDeiE3WnMkb5EoI",
  y: "djI-XqCqSyO9GFk_QT_stROMCAROIvU8KOORBgQUemE",
  d: "5aPFSt0UFVXYGu-ZKyC9FQIUOAMmnjzdIwkxCMe3Iok",
  ext: true,
}
```

So how can I parse my public key Into a `jwk` object. My public key looks like this:
`04f8b2a6e9d2ffa424c3e7b6addf23112153920fd0209390da460f99e03bf8665052e72df4a0b7927381f1b026c98a3a2b348fdd10969875e6b0e86cb1f093a5fc07e49fbbbf091922ce71af17f4a79de03f6069836a7143b137be34451f162235`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer for you but you may want to look at the https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/node-webcrypto-ossl which provides you a webcrypto interface in node. If you dont want to use it directly you can find the answer to your question in its JWK handling.

Comment: Thanks @rmhrisk, but the library does not parse the key to jwk. https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/node-webcrypto-ossl/blob/master/lib/subtle.ts#L424 . I also tried using raw format but I got a `DOMException` saying: `Unsupported import key format for algorithm`

Comment: What browser are you in? Safari has issues with importKey

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Canary, so I suppose that's not the problem.

Comment: Can you provide sample code so I can reproduce the issue, I will look into it. Though maybe creating an issue in the repo for better tracking would be better.

Comment: Nick, this is old but I have confirmed we do support JWK, if you have issues please file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [key-encoder-library](https://github.com/blockstack/key-encoder-js) can help. Try to export as PEM and check if that is working. Consider to create your keys with the node-webcrypto-ossl-lib. The 'jwk'-format is a real help during dev. One can easily clone exported-keys like so :

```
cloneK = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( exportedKey ) )
```